# Try-Catch does not work as expected inside the trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, exception

I have got the follwing `T-sql` inside a proc called from a `Trigger`. The `trigger` itself gets run in another proc and is wrapped in a `transaction`.

```
IF @Email <> ''
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY 
    EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail 
      @profile_name = @MailProfileName,
      @recipients = @Email,
      @subject = @Subject,
      @body = @EmailBody,
      @body_format = @EmailBodyFormat 
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    -- In future this error can be logged to message log or as an action message but ignore for now, it's due to mail profile setting. 
    --SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
  END CATCH
END
```

The problem is that when `@MailProfileName` is an `invalid` profile value then `sp_send_dbmail` raised an error which is fine up to now, but then what I expect from the `try-catch` is to catch this error in the `catch` block and suppress it and let the execution continue on the next line. But what actually happens the whole process crashes as a result of this error.

Does anyone have any idea why it happens.
Ta.

Comment: Please avoid editing the question to include the solution. Instead, answer your own question and accept the answer, so that people will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:
After a little search I came up with this solution:

```
IF @Email <> ''
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY 
    Set xact_abort off
    EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail 
      @profile_name = @MailProfileName,
      @recipients = @Email,
      @subject = @Subject,
      @body = @EmailBody,
      @body_format = @EmailBodyFormat 
  Set xact_abort on
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    -- In future this error can be logged to message log or as an action message but ignore for now, it's due to mail profile setting. 

    --SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
  END CATCH
END
```

But be careful not to use that variable everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the specific question of "why it happens", when the xact_abort is on, the error is causing the entire transaction, which includes the try..catch block, to be rolled back, and the error gets thrown.